# Cascading WHERE Clauses in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for feedback on my solution given that I am in a little over my head in this project. This is in Wordpress.  I am grabbing from the standard `wp_post` and `wp_postmeta` tables.  I am writing an interface with another program so data can be shared between the Wordpress messaging application and my practice management software.  This function clears messages and then permanently deletes them after all within a thread are cleared and both sender and receiver have tagged the message for delete.

I have a situation where I need to cascade a long repeated MySQL SELECT statement with different WHERE clauses.  I tried just using the `$query` statement twice but that ended up just adding the where statements on top of eachother. My solution, which works, is to replicate my SELECT statement in the `$query` variable a second time up top and then concatenate WHERE clauses like this:

```
function action_delmessage($messageid) {
  global $wpdb, $out, $admin_user_login;
  // Get message attributes so we can figure out what to do.

  //Current provider ID 
  $curID = convertToID($admin_user_login);

  $query =  "SELECT uf.user_login AS from_login, ut.user_login AS to_login, pm_clear.meta_key AS clear_p, " .
        "pm_delete1.meta_key AS delete_1 , pm_delete2.meta_key AS delete_2, pm_to.post_id AS parent " .
        "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p " .
        "JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm_to " .
        "ON ((p.post_parent = pm_to.post_id AND p.post_parent <> 0) " .
        "OR (p.id = pm_to.post_id AND p.post_parent = 0)) " .
        "AND pm_to.meta_key = '_fep_participants' " .
        "AND pm_to.meta_value <> p.post_author " .
        "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm_delete1 " . 
        "ON ((pm_delete1.post_id = p.post_parent AND pm_delete1.meta_key = CONCAT('_fep_delete_by_', p.post_author) ) " . 
        "OR (pm_delete1.post_id = p.id AND pm_delete1.meta_key = CONCAT('_fep_delete_by_', p.post_author) )) " . 
        "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm_delete2 " . 
        "ON ((pm_delete2.post_id = p.post_parent AND pm_delete2.meta_key = CONCAT('_fep_delete_by_', pm_to.meta_value) ) " . 
        "OR (pm_delete2.post_id = p.id AND pm_delete2.meta_key = CONCAT('_fep_delete_by_', pm_to.meta_value) )) " . 
        "LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm_clear " .
        "ON ((pm_clear.post_id = p.post_parent AND pm_clear.meta_key = CONCAT('_oemr_fep_clear_', p.id)) " .
        "OR (pm_clear.post_id = p.id AND pm_clear.meta_key = CONCAT('_oemr_fep_clear_', p.id))) " .
        "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users AS uf ON uf.ID = p.post_author " .
        "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users AS ut ON ut.ID = pm_to.meta_value ";
    $query2 = $query;

    $query .= "WHERE p.id = %d";

  $row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, array($messageid)), ARRAY_A);
  if (empty($row)) {
    $out['errmsg'] = "Cannot delete, there is no message with ID $messageid.";
    return;
  }

  $parent = $row['parent'];
  $timestamp = idate("U"); 

  if ($row['from_login'] == $admin_user_login) {
      //clear the record if admin is from
      add_post_meta($messageid, '_oemr_fep_clear_' . $messageid, $timestamp);
  }   

  else if ($row['to_login'] == $admin_user_login) {
      //clear the record if admin is to
      add_post_meta($messageid, '_oemr_fep_clear_' . $messageid, $timestamp);
  } 

  $query2 .=  "WHERE (p.id = %d OR p.post_parent = %d) AND pm_clear.meta_key IS NULL AND p.post_type <> 'attachment'";

  $row2 = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query2, array($parent, $parent)), ARRAY_A);

  if (empty($row2)) {
      add_post_meta($parent, '_fep_delete_by_' . $curID, $timestamp);
  }


    $row3 = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, array($parent)), ARRAY_A);

  if (($row3['delete_1'] !== NULL) && ($row3['delete_2'] !== NULL)) {
    $query4 = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts " .
    "WHERE (ID = %d OR post_parent = %d) and post_type = 'fep_message'", $parent, $parent);
    $row4s = $wpdb->get_results($query4, ARRAY_A);
    foreach ($row4s as $row4) {
        $query5 = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID, post_mime_type, guid " .
        "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts " .
        "WHERE post_parent = %d AND post_type = 'attachment'", $row4['ID']);
        $row5s = $wpdb->get_results($query5, ARRAY_A);
        foreach ($row5s as $row5) {
            $url = $row5['guid'];
            $filename = basename($url);
            $path  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // just the path part of the URL
            $parts = explode('/', $path);           // all the components
            $parts = array_slice($parts, -6);       // the last six
            $path  = implode('/', $parts);  
            $filepath = ABSPATH . $path;
            unlink($filepath); //Delete the file from the server.
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE p FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p WHERE p.id = %d",$row5['ID']));            
        }
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE p, pm FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p " .
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID " .
        "WHERE p.ID = %d OR p.post_parent = %d AND pm.post_id = %d",$row4['ID'],$row4['ID'],$row4['ID']));
    }
  }  
}
```

This is my hacky solution. I am wondering about the correct way to manage these cascading WHERE statements. I am thinking that the way I am replicating `$query` into `$query2` is essentially the same as writing out the select statement again and is probably not the most efficient way to get the job done.  Or, did I actually stumble on a reasonable solution?

Comment: I think you should simplify your query

Comment: I would like to simplify the query.  However this is an interface with another program and I am having to model a table that is like what the other program is expecting.  So in order to do that I have to do a lot of grabbing from the postmeta table which requires all the joins.  So, I do not want to repeat this query.